# Need to delete particular cookie from Firefox addon

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firefox-developer-tools

I need to delete an already set cookie.
Need not to set a cookie from firefox addon. Just locate a cookie and delete that
from the addon code and then fire the api is the requirement.API call has been successfully made.I only need code to delete a cookie from my firefox addon.

I tried this but this is not working .

```
var cookieManager =Cc["@mozilla.org/cookiemanager;1"].getService(Ci.nsICookieManager2);
var cookieCount = cookieManager.getCookiesFromHost("jamdagnirishi.asia");

while (cookieCount.hasMoreElements()) {
  var cookie = e.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsICookie2); 
  dump(cookie.host + ";" + cookie.name + "=" + cookie.value + "\n");
}
```

Note: I have written the above code in bootstrap.js

Answer (score 1):

1. Install fireBug on fire fox.
2. Brows your URL.
3. Press F12 (developer tools will open).
4. Click on **cookies**.
5. Right click on any cookie and select delete.
   [image]

Comment: I have attached the sample code in my query,which means i want to delete the cookies programatically not manually.

Comment: but question title says that you required firefox addon

Answer (score 1):

you can also create/delete cookie using following code,

```
    function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```

you can call this function by Cooke name to delete from developer tool console.
ex: eraseCookie("cookiename")